# How to replace items when I buy another similar item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to replace a wooden sword with a stone sword and a stone/wooden sword with an iron one or a wooden/stone/iron sword with a diamond sword when the new one enters the inventory. Example: I bought the sword pear I need me to remove the wooden sword to put the stone sword.

I'm on Minecraft 1.8.9.

Comment: 2 things: 1) could you please clarify exactly what you are trying to do, and what you've already tried? like, do you want to players to "buy" the item from a menu, by right clicking something in the world, or how else? please be specific, otherwise it's hard to give advice. 2) 1.8.9 has much worse command block support than modern versions, you could probably use a mod or datapack (datapacks are server side so players don't need to install anything for them to work) or some other method to get 1.8 pvp mechanics in modern minecraft

Comment: im trying to detect the new item and remove the older i know i can remove using: /clear <player> minecraft:(item name) but i dont know how to detect the item

Comment: I will assume the item is in the player's inventory. You could use a /scoreboard to keep track of which sword the player has. for example 1 = wood, 2 = stone, etc. when they buy a sword upgrade you /clear the item and /give @a[score={}] (give item based on score). you could also check with /entitydata or by other means what sword to give them. If you do not know how to format these commands yet then I reccomend using mcstacker. here is a version that should work for minecraft 1.8: https://legacy.mcstacker.net/mcstacker1.10.php

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with 1.8 commands but I think something like `/clear player stone sword` after you give them an iron sword.